# Add a space for every symbol matched from excel sheet with perl

Tags: perl, cell, spreadsheet

I am using the Spreadsheet::ParseExcel module for getting values from an excel sheet and storing them in an array. I am able to save the numeric values from a particular column of the spreadsheet, however some of the values have question marks (?) wher it isn't defined. I need a gap to be included where this happens in the array. I am unable to find a way to do this. Here is my code as of now.

```
    for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( $col_min ) {

            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $one );
            next unless $cell;
            $cell->value();
    my $cell_type = $cell->{Type};
            if ($cell_type =~/Numeric/)
        {
            push @firstvalues, $cell->unformatted();
    }
    elsif ($cell =~ m/\?/ )
    {
    push @firstvalues, "";
    }
        }
```

any advice is appreciated on how I could add a blank for every match of "?" symbol in an excel cell coz this doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply need to rewrite the line

```
elsif ($cell =~ m/\?/ )
```

into

```
elsif ($cell->unformatted() =~ m/\?/ )
```

Then you will get the correct result. With some test data from me (third row has `?`)

```
print join(' - ',@firstvalues), "\n";

1 - 2 -  - 4
```